# Decent buffer size for file reading then sending out packets

Tags: file, networking, file-io, stream, buffer

I have a little web server application which reads `X` bytes from a file stream then outputs those bytes to an open TCP stream.

I played around with it a little bit and, for example, having a buffer size of 1024 then bumping it up 5120 didn't see much improvement. I also tried making it with a size of 1, to which I saw a huge speed decrease.

I know I'm going to be limited by the read speed of the medium, and also by the network, so I'm curious about how to set this number. Is there a certain number I can set this to which will be optimal in all situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a certain number I can set this to which will be optimal in all situations?

No, because it depends on the factors you mentioned, as well as on the buffering in your I/O library and in the operating system. Using some value that is a multiple of the disk block size, memory page size, and/or network packet size (don't forget the protocol headers!) is generally a wise move, though.

If speed is essential, then don't copy the blocks though memory at all if you can avoid it. Linux, for example, has the [`sendfile`](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sendfile.2.html) system call for this.

Comment: Is there a consequence for using a high number as there would be with using a low number?

Comment: @Tim Cooper: yes, while the server is filling its large buffers, the client has nothing to process/display. Initial page load time increases, perceived performance decreases.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a certain number. But running a lot of test with different buffer dimension and perhaps using a network simulation tool to simulate different network conditions, could help a lot in selecting different suitable buffer dimension. I played this way while optimizing a VoIP client and it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The more important factor is the socket send buffer size. Set this to at least 32k.